# h:graphicImage title - formatted text

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2

Can I use html attributes inside the title of a < h:graphicImage > ?

I'd like something like:

```
<h:graphicImage value="/images/box.gif" title="#{literal}"/>
```

where `#{literal}` is a String: `< b > BoldText < /b >`

Can the title attribute interpret the `< b>` tag?

Comment: What if I want only a word inside the string to be bold?
ex: #{literal}="This is a <b>bold</b> text"

Answer (score 1):

Since you are tagged with html, i answer you in `HTML + CSS`. you can do by setting some styles for attribute using **CSS**.

**Html code:**

```
<a href="#" title="This is link">Hi., Buddy.!!</a>
```

**CSS code:**

```
a {
  color: #900;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
}

a[title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #eeeeee),color-stop(1, #cccccc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
}
```

**Demo in JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/f29uq/

Hope this helps..!!